# I need to modify a value with a function that is run by exec(), but the value resets after execution

Tags: python, exec, python-3.7

I'm writing a compiler for a programming language and I need to run a function with exec. The function modifies a value, but it always resets after executing the function.

I'm using python 3.7, running under raspbian on a raspi 3 b. I've already tried using locals(), but it does not help

```py
buffer = ""

def write():
    buffer = "Hello World"

_locals = locals()

exec('write()', globals(), _locals)

buffer = _locals['buffer']
print(buffer)
```

I expect it to output `Hello World`, but it doesn't output at all.
No errors, just

Comment: `buffer` is local to `write`, not local to the scope in which `write` is called nor a global.

Comment: @chepner how do i fix it

Comment: Jake: Add a `global buffer` to the beginning of the function.

Comment: martineau It doesn't help. I at least get a blank line now, but no text. Thanks for the fast response anyway